# Adding password masking to a script

Tags: batch-file

For practice, I am writing a program to hide a folder. The program itself is working perfectly, but I want to mask my input with asterisks (*). I have found code that masks input as a standalone script, but I can't figure out a way to integrate the code into mine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### program code

```
@echo off
color 5F
title Folder Locker by KBKOZLEV
:SETPASS
set "tipp="
set "password="
if exist "password.txt" (
    set /p password=<password.txt
    attrib +h +s "password.txt"
)
if exist "tipp.txt" (
    set /p tipp=<tipp.txt
    attrib +h +s "tipp.txt"
)
:START
if exist "Locked" goto OPEN
if exist "Unlocked" goto LOCK
if not exist "Unlocked" goto MDLOCKER
:LOCK
ren "Unlocked" "Locked"
attrib +h +s "Locked"
echo.
echo Folder locked.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
exit
:MDLOCKER
md "Unlocked"
echo>password.txt 1234
echo>tipp.txt 1234
attrib +h +s "password.txt"
attrib +h +s "tipp.txt"
cls
echo.
echo Private folder created successfully.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
goto END
:OPEN
color 2F
cls
echo.
echo Password tipp: %tipp%
echo.
echo Enter password to unlock folder or
echo enter "new" to set a new password.
echo.
set "pass="
set /p "pass=Password: "
if /i "%pass%"=="new" goto NEWPASS
if "%pass%"=="%password%" (
    attrib -h -s "Locked"
    ren "Locked" "Unlocked"
    echo.
    echo Folder unlocked successfully.
    goto END
)
goto FAIL
:FAIL
color 4F  
cls
echo.
echo Invalid password, please try again.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
cls
goto OPEN
:NEWPASS
color 8F
cls
echo.
set "oldpass="
set /p "oldpass=Old password: "
if not "%oldpass%"=="%password%" goto FAIL
:ENTERNEW
color 8F
cls
echo.
set "newpass=""
set /p "newpass=New password: "
set newpass=%newpass:"=%
if "%newpass%"=="" (
    echo.
    echo Invalid new password, please enter new password again.
    CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
    goto ENTERNEW
)
if exist "password.txt" attrib -h -s "password.txt"
echo>password.txt %newpass%
echo.
set "passtipp=""
set /p "passtipp=New tipp: "
set passtipp=%passtipp:"=% 
if exist "tipp.txt" attrib -h -s "tipp.txt"
if not "%passtipp%"=="" (
    echo>tipp.txt %passtipp%
) else (
    del "tipp.txt" 
)
goto SETPASS 
:END
```

### masking code

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set /P "=Enter a Password:" < Nul
Call :PasswordInput
Echo(Your input was:!Line!

Goto :Eof

:PasswordInput
::Author: Carlos Montiers Aguilera
::Last updated: 20150401. Created: 20150401. 
::Set in variable Line a input password
For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'"Echo(|Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W"') Do Set "CR=%%#"
For /F %%# In (
'"Prompt $H &For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do Set "BS=%%#"
Set "Line="
:_PasswordInput_Kbd
Set "CHR=" & For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W') Do Set "CHR=%%#"
If !CHR!==!CR! Echo(&Goto :Eof
    If !CHR!==!BS! (If Defined Line (Set /P "=!BS! !BS!" <Nul
        Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
    )
) Else (Set /P "=*" <Nul
If !CHR!==! (Set "Line=!Line!^!"
    ) Else Set "Line=!Line!!CHR!"
)
Goto :_PasswordInput_Kbd
```

Comment: I refuse to believe that you haven't simply tried to copy the second script into the first script, because that's literally all you have to do. What have you tried, and what output are you receiving from what you have tried?

Comment: It seems that you should be able to provide a more minimalistic example that highlights more clearly what's going wrong.

Comment: I tried to copy it and use the Call command to call the srcirpt. It masket the input, but did not allow for the program to contiunie. In other words after entering the password, when I hit Enter, instead of further executing the code the "enter" input was also masked. So I could not do anything, as everything I typed was just masked.

Comment: The second script puts a Carriage Return (CR) into a variable. If this is not done correctly the input loop will continue endlessly. I'd check that constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the *merged* script. Note changes in original `:PasswordInput` procedure (and in your original code, all `cls` replaced by `rem cls` merely for debugging purposes):

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

color 5F
title Folder Locker by KBKOZLEV
:SETPASS
set "tipp="
set "password="
if exist "password.txt" (
    set /p password=<password.txt
    attrib +h +s "password.txt"
)
if exist "tipp.txt" (
    set /p tipp=<tipp.txt
    attrib +h +s "tipp.txt"
)

:START
if exist "Locked" goto :OPEN
if exist "Unlocked" goto :LOCK
if not exist "Unlocked" goto :MDLOCKER

:LOCK
ren "Unlocked" "Locked"
attrib +h +s "Locked"
echo(
echo Folder locked.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
goto :END
exit

:MDLOCKER
md "Unlocked"
echo>password.txt 1234
echo>tipp.txt 1234
attrib +h +s "password.txt"
attrib +h +s "tipp.txt"
rem cls
echo(
echo Private folder created successfully.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
goto :END

:OPEN
color 2F
rem cls
echo(
echo Password tipp: %tipp%
echo(
echo Enter password to unlock folder or
echo enter "new" to set a new password.
echo(
set "pass="
rem set /p "pass=Password: "
Set /P "=Password:" < Nul
Call :PasswordInput pass

if /i "%pass%"=="new" goto :NEWPASS
if "%pass%"=="%password%" (
    attrib -h -s "Locked"
    ren "Locked" "Unlocked"
    echo(
    echo Folder unlocked successfully.
    goto :END
)
goto :FAIL

:FAIL
color 4F  
rem cls
echo(
echo Invalid password, please try again.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
rem cls
goto :OPEN

:NEWPASS
color 8F
rem cls
echo(
set "oldpass="
rem set /p "oldpass=Old password: "
Set /P "=Old Password:" < Nul
Call :PasswordInput oldpass

if not "%oldpass%"=="%password%" goto :FAIL

:ENTERNEW
color 8F
rem cls
echo(
set "newpass=""
rem set /p "newpass=New password: "
Set /P "=New Password:" < Nul
Call :PasswordInput newpass

set newpass=%newpass:"=%
if "%newpass%"=="" (
    echo(
    echo Invalid new password, please enter new password again.
    CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
    goto :ENTERNEW
)
if exist "password.txt" attrib -h -s "password.txt"
echo>password.txt %newpass%
echo(
set "passtipp=""
set /p "passtipp=New tipp: "
set passtipp=%passtipp:"=% 
if exist "tipp.txt" attrib -h -s "tipp.txt"
if not "%passtipp%"=="" (
    echo>tipp.txt %passtipp%
) else (
    del "tipp.txt" 
)
goto :SETPASS 

:END
color
EndLocal
Goto :Eof

:PasswordInput
::Author: Carlos Montiers Aguilera
::Last updated: 20150401. Created: 20150401. 
::Set in variable Line a input password
::
::Update 20150503: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz?tab=profile
::Changes made in next lines:
::    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::    If !CHR!==!CR! Echo(&EndLocal&set "%1=%Line%"&Goto :Eof
::Usage:
::    Call :PasswordInput variableName
::where variableName is a name of output variable (by reference call)
:: 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'"Echo(|Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W"') Do Set "CR=%%#"
For /F %%# In (
'"Prompt $H &For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do Set "BS=%%#"
Set "Line="
:_PasswordInput_Kbd
Set "CHR=" & For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
    'Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W') Do Set "CHR=%%#"
If !CHR!==!CR! Echo(&EndLocal&set "%1=%Line%"&Goto :Eof
    If !CHR!==!BS! (If Defined Line (Set /P "=!BS! !BS!" <Nul
        Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
    )
) Else (Set /P "=*" <Nul
If !CHR!==! (Set "Line=!Line!^!"
    ) Else Set "Line=!Line!!CHR!"
)
Goto :_PasswordInput_Kbd
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a small hybride **[Batch/VBS/HTA]** to mask password typed by user; so get inspired by this code and try to intgreate it in your main project ;)

```
@echo off
Title Générer un HTABOX pour cacher un mot de passe en ligne de commande Copyright Hackoo 2014
mode con cols=90 lines=3 & color 9B
Set MyVBSFile=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
Set MyHTAFile=%tmp%\%~n0.hta
:: Créer le VBS Pour extraire et générer le code du HTA
Call :CreateMyVBS
:: Lancer Le VBS
Cscript.exe //NOLOGO %MyVBSFile%
:: Lancer Le HTA crée par le VBS
start /wait mshta.exe "%MyHTAFile%"
Del "%MyVBSFile%" & Del "%MyHTAFile%"
:: Lire le contenu du fichier %tmp%\userIn pour extraire le mot de passe et tapé depuis
:: le HTABOX et le définir comme une variable
for /f %%i in (%tmp%\userIn) do set "Mypassword=%%i"
echo Votre mot de passe saisi est : %MyPassword%
Del %tmp%\userIn
pause
Exit /b
:#Start
<html>
<head>
<title>Mot de Passe © Hackoo</title>
<hta:application id="htaid"
applicationName="Password"
border="thin"
icon="wlrmdr.exe"
borderStyle="normal"
caption="yes"
contextMenu="no"
maximizeButton="no"
minimizeButton="yes"
navigable="yes"
showInTaskbar="yes"
singleInstance="yes"
sysmenu="yes"
SCROLL="NO"
SHOWINTASKBAR="Yes"  
SELECTION="no"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
>
</head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
<BODY TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1"><CENTER><DIV><SPAN ID="ONSCR"></SPAN></DIV></CENTER></BODY>
<script language="vbscript">
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Window_OnLoad
    CenterWindow 300,150
    Call PasswordForm()
    Call TextFocus()
end sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub SavePassword()
    set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFile=fs.GetAbsolutePathName(fs.BuildPath(fs.GetSpecialFolder(2),"UserIn"))
    set ts=fs.OpenTextFile(strFile,2,True)
    If PasswordArea.value <> "" Then
        ts.WriteLine PasswordArea.value
        ts.Close
        self.Close 'Pour fermer ce HTA après avoir enregistré le mot de passe comme une variable dans le fichier Userin
    else
        Msgbox "Le mot de passe est vide ! "& Vbcrlf & "SVP entrez de nouveau votre mot de passe",VbExclamation,"Mot de Passe © Hackoo"
        Location.reload(true) 'Pour recharger à nouveau ce HTA
    end if
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub PasswordForm()
    Self.document.title = "Mot de Passe © Hackoo"
    Self.document.bgColor = "lightblue"
    ONSCR.InnerHTML="<center><FONT COLOR=""#FFFFFF"" SIZE=""+1"" FACE=""VERDANA,ARIAL,HELVETICA,SANS-SERIF"">Taper votre mot de passe</FONT<br>"_
    &"<input type=""password"" name=""PasswordArea"" size=""20"" onKeyUp=""TextFocus""><br><br><input type=""Submit"" STYLE=""HEIGHT:25;WIDTH:110"" value=""OK"" onClick=""SavePassword"">"
END Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub TextFocus
    PasswordArea.Focus
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</script>
</body>
</html>
:#End
::***********************************************************************************************
:CreateMyVBS
::'**********************************************************************************************
(
echo. Set fso = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo. Set f=fso.opentextfile^("%~f0",1^)
echo. a=f.readall
echo. Set r=new regexp
echo. r.pattern = "(?:^|(?:\r\n))(?::#Start\r\n)([\s\S]*?)(?:\r\n)(?::#End)"
echo. Set Matches = r.Execute^(a^)
echo. If Matches.Count ^> 0 Then Data = Matches^(0^).SubMatches^(0^)
echo. WriteFileText "%MyHTAFile%",Data
echo. f.close
::'**********************************************************************************************
echo.
echo. Function WriteFileText^(sFile,Data^)
echo.     Dim objFSO,oTS,sText
echo.     Set objFSO = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo.     Set oTS = objFSO.CreateTextFile^(sFile,2^)
echo.     oTS.WriteLine Data
echo.     oTS.close
echo.     set oTS = nothing
echo.     Set objFSO = nothing
echo. End Function
) > %MyVBSFile%
::'***********************************************************************************************
```