# Is it possible to capture a password in cmd Net Use?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

bat script to get a users name and password to connect to shared network drives, the key element is:

```
net use u: \\server\users\%UserName% * /user:%UserName% /persistent:no
```

This works great as the password prompt is requested by the "*" which is hidden from view and I have already captured the user's login name. Mapping to other locations on the same server works without any further user input but as soon as I map to another server the user will be prompted to input their password again.

Is there anyway I can capture the entry typed at "*" to apply to a string for the other servers?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use Powershell for something like this--use input prompts to get the username and password into variables, and then run the "net use" command with the variables.

Comment: Agreed. Use PowerShell. Much simpler than using Cmd.exe shell scripts (batch files).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses, unfortunately my email, must be blocking the replies as I didn't get any notifications.

I've never used PowerShell so that would be another learning curve and JosefZ's post certainly will be reviewed.

I did some more intensive searching out of work hours and located a command based utility:

EditVar/EditV32/EditV64 and Choose/Choose32/Choose64
(C) 2006-2014 by Bill Stewart (bstewart@iname.com)

This resides in the same location as the orinal script and just requires a line to call it and assign a string, in the example below %PASSWORD% will be the string which I can then use in place of "*", works a treat.

```
editv64 -p "Enter your password: " PASSWORD -m
```

Good to get feed back and I'll be sorting my email filters out - Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[A clone from my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30018855/3439404):

```
Set /P "=Type the password for \\server\users\%UserName%:" < Nul
Call :PasswordInput serverpass
net use u: \\server\users\%UserName% %serverpass% /user:%UserName% /persistent:no

rem skip over the procedure 
goto :eof
:PasswordInput
::Author: Carlos Montiers Aguilera
::Last updated: 20150401. Created: 20150401. 
::Set in variable Line a input password
::
::Update 20150503: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz?tab=profile
::Changes made in next lines:
::    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::    If !CHR!==!CR! Echo(&EndLocal&set "%1=%Line%"&Goto :Eof
::Usage:
::    Call :PasswordInput variableName
::where variableName is a name of output variable (by reference call)
:: 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'"Echo(|Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W"') Do Set "CR=%%#"
For /F %%# In (
'"Prompt $H &For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do Set "BS=%%#"
Set "Line="
:_PasswordInput_Kbd
Set "CHR=" & For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
    'Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W') Do Set "CHR=%%#"
If !CHR!==!CR! Echo(&EndLocal&set "%1=%Line%"&Goto :Eof
    If !CHR!==!BS! (If Defined Line (Set /P "=!BS! !BS!" <Nul
        Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
    )
) Else (Set /P "=*" <Nul
If !CHR!==! (Set "Line=!Line!^!"
    ) Else Set "Line=!Line!!CHR!"
)
Goto :_PasswordInput_Kbd
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell sample script to read hidden input string and pass to multiple `net use` commands:

```
Function Read-Password {
  param(
    [String] $promptString
  )
  $secureString = Read-Host $promptString -AsSecureString
  try {
    $intPtr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
    $password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($intPtr)
  }
  finally {
    if ( $intPtr ) {
      [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($intPtr)
    }
  }
  $password
}

$password = Read-Password "Enter password"
if ( -not $password ) { return }

net use \\server1\share /user:foo $password
net use \\server2\share /user:foo $password
# ... etc.
```