# In batch password protecting a file how can i convert it to an asterisk?

Tags: batch-file, passwords

```
    cls
    @ECHO OFF
    color 0c
    title Folder Secure
    if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
    if NOT EXIST Secure goto MDLOCKER
    :CONFIRM
    echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N)
    set/p "cho=>"
    if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
    if %cho%==y goto LOCK
    if %cho%==n goto END
    if %cho%==N goto END
    echo Invalid choice.
    goto CONFIRM
    :LOCK
    ren Secure "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
    attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
    echo Folder locked
    goto End
    :UNLOCK
    echo Enter the Password to unlock folder
    set/p "pass=>"
    if NOT %pass%== access1221 goto FAIL
    attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
    ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Secure
    echo Folder Unlocked successfully
    goto End
    :FAIL
    echo Invalid password
    goto end
    :MDLOCKER
    md Secure
    echo Secure created successfully
    goto End
    :End
```

Can someone edit this to hide the inputted password with asterisks. Most of the entries i saw used a long method which did not seem to be compatible with this particular program.
Thanks.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file

Comment: thanks but i dont want to use VB script which is only compatible with windows server and 2003

Comment: @SaurontheMighty, I use VBscript on every version of Windows since XP, including the server versions (2003, 2008, 2012)

Comment: Look at this thread on [dostips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4664#p26788)

Comment: @SaurontheMighty - check all the answsers . There are more than enough solutions that not relly on the not suported wsh components.

Comment: I am using VBScript in some of my programs and I am using windows 10....

Comment: @SaurontheMighty you can take a look at this : [Adding password masking to a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012711/adding-password-masking-to-a-script/30017016#30017016)

Comment: getpwd.cmd:
@echo off
<nul: set /p passwd=Password: 
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cscript /nologo getpwd.vbs') do set passwd=%%i
echo.
getpwd.vbs:
Set oScriptPW = CreateObject("ScriptPW.Password")
strPassword = oScriptPW.GetPassword()
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine strPassword
I added this to the top of my program but its not working. Can seomeone add it to the program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mask an input text in a bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file)